# align ionic card to flex end

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I tried to make an ionic card start from bottom of the page using align-item: flex-end, but it did not affect.

This is the code:

```
    <div class="align-page">
    <div class="first-section">
      <ion-chip [outline]="true" class="selected">One</ion-chip>
      <ion-chip class="not-selected">Two</ion-chip>
      <ion-chip class="not-selected">Three</ion-chip>
    </div>

    <div class="second-section">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-subtitle>hi</ion-card-subtitle>
          <ionc-item>
            <ion-row style="height: 10px"></ion-row>
          </ionc-item>
        <ion-card-content>

    </div> 
</div>

.align-page{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-item: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace flex-direction:column with

**justify-content: flex-end;**

The column is a flex container

But you have to justify also content to end. Default value is strech for justify-content.
Hope it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.